# ASCII codes appear in Excel '03 but not '07

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2003, character-encoding, ascii

Part I - I have a spreadsheet that was from data exported from an application.  When I open it, I can see the 'boxes' that usually are from a line break or paragraph break in a cell.  IF I view the spreadsheet in my version of excel 2003, I can see them just fine and know where to look to get rid of them, and when they are gone.  If I open it on another PC in Excel 2007, I can not see them to even know they are there to cause the problem.

Q - is there a way to view these boxes, this code, in Excel 2007?

Part II - sometimes, I can use a formula to scrub out these boxes, but sometimes the formula does not remove all.  Any advice on how to make sure I get them all?  Hard to see sometimes in a spreadsheet with over 5,000 rows of data.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[`CLEAN`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP052090141033.aspx) should remove all funny characters below 31.

See also Microsoft's [Remove spaces and nonprinting characters from text](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP030561311033.aspx) and [Top ten ways to clean your data](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HA102218401033.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

=substitute(substitute(a1,char(13)," "),char(11)," ")
should get rid of carriage returns and line breaks and replaces them with spaces.  If you have any other special characters use =code to find out their ascii values and add a substitute for them